# Migrating to Hibernate 5.2 is giving error Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not determine a type for class: java.util.Collection

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1, hibernate-5.x

I am using spring project. Here is my POM snippet

```
.....
<!-- Spring Data module for JPA repositories. -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>  //1.10.1.RELEASE
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>${javax.persistence.version}</version>  //2.1.1
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate entity manager with JPA 2 support. 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate-entitymanager.version}</version>  // 5.1.0.Final
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>${javassist.version}</version>    // 3.20.0-GA
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>   // 5.2.4.Final
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>  // 5.2.4.Final
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
.....
```

I have a spring Data JPA repository

```
public interface LmsRoleLmsFeatureRepository extends CrudRepository<LmsRoleLmsFeature, Long> {
    List<LmsRoleLmsFeature> findByLmsRoleIdIn(Collection<Long> ids);
}
```

Here is my spring configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.PROXY, proxyTargetClass = false, order = 2)
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "a.b.c.repositories",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager"
)
@Import({DatabasePropertiesConfig.class})
public class PersistenceConfig {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_MAX_FETCH_DEPTH = "hibernate.max_fetch_depth";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_JDBC_FETCH_SIZE = "hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_JDBC_BATCH_SIZE = "hibernate.jdbc.batch_size";

    private static final String[] ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = {"a.b.c.entities", "a.b.c.converters"};

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
         JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
         transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
         return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdaptor() {
         HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
         return vendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdaptor());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);   
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setSharedCacheMode(SharedCacheMode.ENABLE_SELECTIVE);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setValidationMode(ValidationMode.NONE);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaHibernateProperties());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties jpaHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
         properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
         properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_MAX_FETCH_DEPTH, env.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_MAX_FETCH_DEPTH));
         properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_JDBC_FETCH_SIZE, env.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_JDBC_FETCH_SIZE));
         properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_JDBC_BATCH_SIZE, env.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_JDBC_BATCH_SIZE));

         return properties;       
    }

}
```

This code works fine. When I run my application Spring application context is load properly. But when I change my application to hibernate 5.2. As I read from [Hibernate ORM 5.2 release](http://in.relation.to/2016/06/01/hibernate-orm-520-final-release/) that **hibernate-entitymanager module no longer exists. Its functionality has been consolidated into hibernate-core**. So I changed my POM to this

```
....
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>   //5.2.0.Final
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate entity manager with JPA 2 support. 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate-entitymanager.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
            <exclusions>
                ...
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
-->

.....
```

See comment out my `hibernate-entitymanager` dependency and include just `hibernate-core` dependency. But now when I run my application I get the following error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lmsRoleLmsFeatureRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not determine a type for class: java.util.Collection
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
.....
.....
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not determine a type for class: java.util.Collection
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.resolveParameterBindType(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1023) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.0.Final.jar:5.2.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaBuilderImpl.parameter(CriteriaBuilderImpl.java:588) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.0.Final.jar:5.2.0.Final]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterMetadataProvider.next(ParameterMetadataProvider.java:161) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterMetadataProvider.next(ParameterMetadataProvider.java:138) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:?]
```

If I change from `Collection` to `List`. Then I get the same error for `List`. I also tried with just

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

But same error. Why I am getting this error. Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks & Regards

Basit Mahmood Ahmed

Comment: Spring Data JPA and Spring don't support Hibernate 5.2 yet (fully that is). There are patches for 5.2 in the latest Spring Data JPA snapshot which you could try.

Comment: HHmm it means currently with spring use 5.1.0. Once spring announce with hibernate 5.2 changes. Then it is better to move on Hibernate 5.2 with Spring ?

Comment: See https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14327 and https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-911 . I guess you need to wait until those are resolved and it probably involves upgrading Spring as well as Spring Data JPA.

Comment: Hmm thanks. Now I am waiting for spring upgrade :)

Comment: Upgraded to `spring 4.3.0.RELEASE` and `spring data jpa 1.10.2` release. But still getting the same error ... using the same configuration posted in my question.

Comment: This issue has been resolved in hibernate 5.2.1. Migrating hibernate-core to 5.2.1 resolved the issue. Thanks

Comment: @Basit 5.2.1 and spring-data-jpa 1.10.2 still has the problem.

Comment: Ah no I am suing spring 4.3.1, spring-data-jpa 1.10.2 , hibernate-core 5.2.1 and everything is working fine. I mean the error that I was getting is gone. I upgraded it yesterday and test then I replied. Hmm what error are you getting ?

Comment: @Xiangyu You are not using Spring Boot and have some outdated transitive dependencies on classpath, namely `spring-orm` and `spring-tx`

Comment: Yup I am using spring not spring boot. May be spring boot have issues. But with spring everything is working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here in spring boot forums](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6111), use the 5.2.1.Final Hibernate version and it should resolve this issue.

I could replicate your problem in spring boot with 5.2.0. Changing to 5.2.1.Final worked for me.